ASP.NET Core app consuming too much memory in kubernetes
I have a asp.net core 6.0 app that performs simple operation to read objects from database and convert to JSON. We retrieve only 50 objects at a time and the columns are around 5-8 mostly.
The situation is when we deploy this app in linux container running in Kubernetes and perform basic testing i.e. send 500 messages with in a time frame of 20 min the memory shoots up and never settles down.
grafana memory graph
However, in local docker desktop environment, the same tests shows a contant memory consumption of ~1GB.
docker desktop memory stats
i ran memory profiler to see any memory leaks in the application, but the profiler shows no such memory issues. Below graph shows the snapshots.
memory profiler
App reclaims the memory when a Gen2 collection happens.
i tried using servergarbagecollection false/true both show significant growth in memory in Kubernetes.
we have set memory limit to 8GB and cpu limit to 2500m for our service in Kubernetes.
can some one provide any advise on this situation? any troubleshooting tips?

I don't think that without knowing what code you're deploying we can help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
